# Variable passed to function using ng-model stays undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

After creating a table, I want to send the value inside one of its `<td>`s to a function using ng-model but the variable stays undefined no matter what I try.
The variable should contain the value inside the cell that called `saveCron()` . Problem started when I tried to break the value inside the cron_format cell. I'm splitting the value with the `letters()` function:

```
$scope.letters = function(rawname) {
    var lettersarray = rawname.split(" ");
    return lettersarray;
};
```

And now each of the chars has its own input field, instead of all the cron_format value in one input field.

The table looks like this:

```
<table  ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <thead>
    <th>user name</th>
    <th>script name</th>
    <th>cron format</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,row) in data">
    <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in row">
        <td>{{user(user_id)}}</td>
        <td>{{script(script_id)}}</td>
        <td ng-model="vm.l">
            <input type="text" ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index"  value="{{letter}}"/>
            <button ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)">save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And `saveCron()` like this:

```
$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat){
    console.log($scope.vm.l);
}
```

*in practice I have a bit more :) complicated logic inside the function but for simplicity purposes I will leave the function like this.

Bottom line: how can I pass to saveCron() the entire value inside the `<td>` that created the call?

Example: if the `<td>` code looks like this:

```
<td ng-model="vm.l">
<input value="1"><input value="2"><input value="3">
</td>
```

The function will get (log) "123" and if user edited some of the input fields, lets say to:

```
<td ng-model="vm.l">
<input value="4"><input value="2"><input value="4">
</td>
```

And clicked save,function will get 424...
Any help please?

Comment: change td to `<td ng-model="vm.l">
            <input type="text" ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index"  value="{{letter}}" ng-model="letter"/>
            <button ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)">save</button>
        </td>` now this will do two way binding

Comment: unfortunately. still getting this error in the console: `Cannot read property 'l' of undefined`

Comment: ng- model="vm.l" you cant get this inside your scope

Comment: sorry im kind of new to angular...can u please explain what u mean?

Comment: You have quite a few issues going on here, ill try to explain in an answer.

Comment: what value should you expect to come in vm.l

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so there's a few issues here. I'll do my best to hit them all clearly.

So basically you are going to be better off rewriting this.

First of all, you are trying to access "vm.1", normally angular would create a variable for you without needing to define it. But since you are using an object, it needs to be defined as such. So in your controller doing.

```
$scope.vm = {};
```

will solve that problem.

Second, you should put your ng-model on the input itself, instead of the wrapper, it doesn't work the way you have it setup now. The ng-model is not tied to anything and will never update.

Now there are a few different ways to handle how you get these values. I will assume what you are trying to do is give people the ability to change these values and then run some function off of it. Correct?

Here is how I would do it...

```
<td>
  <input ng-repeat='letter in whatever' ng-model='vm[user_id][$index]' value='{{letter}}'/>
  <button ng-click='saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,vm[user_id])>Save</button>
</td>
```

So this will send the data for each group of inputs straight into the function. So your function would then be...

```
$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat,data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Something along these lines will work for you. Your ng-repeats are also very messy, so I would look into redoing those as well.

**Edit**
Forgot to mention doing it this way, your data will come through as an object with key : value